# How do I avoid using these functions before they are defined when I'm coding a circular check in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, circular-reference

I keep finding myself in these loops where I'm working through user input to make sure I'm getting what's expected. However, I don't know how to do this without calling a function before it is defined, which gives me eslint error: [no-use-before-define](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define).

```
function tryAgain(){
  alertBadInput();
  getInput();
}

function getInput(){
  var input = askForInput();
  if (input === 'bad') {
    tryAgain();
    return;
  }
  processInput(input);
}
```

No matter what order I define these two functions, one of them will be calling another before it is defined.

It seems syntactically valid, but given the eslint error, what other pattern can I use if I were hoping to avoid that error?

Comment: Are you returning after `tryAgain();`? That's the only issue I see here. Also, nothing wrong with your code here, perfectly acceptable to define 2 functions that call each other.

Comment: Should read up on how *"javascript hoisting"* works. Function declarations get hoisted during compile phase and before anything gets called

Comment: @FrankerZ Yup - realized my mistake as you wrote that... So this is OK? (I'm just getting eslint errors)

Comment: @charlietfl Well, I have read up on hoisting... but eslint complains. I'll add that in the question.

Comment: @Trees4theForest "OK" for who? It's syntactically valid.

Comment: "which gives me eslint error: no-use-before-define." --- ask your eslint policies author how to handle such cases then. The community has no idea about coding standards in your company.

Comment: @zerkms Syntactically valid = OK in my book. I guess a sub question here would be how to avoid this kind of case... but if it's valid, I'm not going to worry too much about it.

Comment: it's syntactically valid: run it in your browser and see it.

Comment: The linter is designed to help you follow best practices, but because of hoisting, calling a function before its declaration is not an error. Is it a good idea to try to declare before you call? Sure, but is it completely avoidable? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it might be ok for two functions to call each other, you might be better of using a `while` loop for clarity (and that's what it's for) and to comply with the coding standard avoiding the error altogether, like so:

```
function getInput() {
    var no_valid_input = true;
    var input = null;
    while (no_valid_input) {
        input = askForInput();
        if (input !== 'bad') {
            no_valid_input = false;
        } else {
            alertBadInput();
        }
    }
    processInput();
}
```

Working example:

```js
function processInput() {
    return alert('Yep, processing...');
}
function alertBadInput() {
    return alert('Nope');
}
function askForInput() {
    return prompt('What?');
}

function getInput() {
    var no_valid_input = true;
    var input = null;
    while (no_valid_input) {
        input = askForInput();
        if (input !== 'bad') {
            no_valid_input = false;
        } else {
            alertBadInput();
        }
    }
    processInput();
}

getInput();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Disabling the error

Although it doesn't really *solve* the problem, it may make sense to disable it for a specific use-case.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
```

Use it like this:

```
function tryAgain(){
  alertBadInput();
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
  getInput();
}

function getInput(){
  var input = askForInput();
  if (input === 'bad') {
    tryAgain();
    return;
  }
  processInput(input);
}
```

---

#### Use-case

I've had to use this in a module with a class where I did not want to expose my class-specific function (with similar format to the following code). Flipping the class and function around yields the same eslint error.

It'll either be:

- `prepare` before `Request` where `Request` is used by `prepare`, or
- `Request` before `prepare` where `prepare` is used by `Request`.

This is obviously a simplification, but gives you the general idea:

```
// function that I don't export
function prepare(request) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
    if (request instanceof Request) {
        return JSON.stringify(request.obj)
    } else {
        return new TypeError('Wrong type given, expected Request')
    }
}

// class that export that uses the prepare function
class Request{
    constructor() {
        this.obj = {}
    }
    
    doSomething() {
        const request = prepare(this)
        // do something with request
    }
    
    addX(x) {
        this.obj.x = x
    }
}

module.exports = Request
```

Comment: Thanks! I am aware you can disable eslint rules on a line-by-line basis, was just looking for ways to fix code /without/ reverting to that.